# Extract data into new workbook based on value in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, excel-2010, vba

I want to extract data from one speadsheet to another based on value of a particular cell.

I want to extract data to a new workbook based on Product. For example, Data for all the customer who purchased HDD should be moved to a new workbook and data for all customer who purchased monitor should be moved to another workbook. I 257 different product types, so data needs to be send to 257 different workbooks.

I was just wondering if there is any feature in excel through which we can search for value(Product in this senario) and move it to another worksheet.

Can anyone please help me regarding this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately excell is notably lacking in this department... If it is feasible (willing to move to different package?) you might consider using FILTER() function within Google Sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As tkacprow said there is no 'out of the box' tool that wil do this for you in excel. You will ideally need a VBA macro to do this.

I have just uploaded to my website an example tool/workbook which has the required VBA macro built into it. Feel free to utilise and change this to meet you needs http://tomwinslow.co.uk/handy-excel-tools/.

Let me know if this is not exactly what you are looking for and I can try amend it.

Hope this helps.

Below is the code incase you would prefer it, rather than downloading from my site.

```
Sub splitMasterList()

    Dim MAST As Worksheet
    Set MAST = Sheets("MASTER")


    Dim headerRng As Range
    Dim areaSelectionCount As Long
    Dim areaSelectionIsValid As Boolean
    Dim areaSelectionRow As Long
    Dim splitColRng As Range
    Dim themeExists As Boolean
    Dim themeArray() As String
    ReDim Preserve themeArray(1 To 1)
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastSheetTabRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ii As Long
    Dim theme As String
    Dim doesSheetExist As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sheetTabRowCounter As Long



    'ask the user to highlight the table header
    On Error Resume Next
    Set headerRng = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please select the headings of all columns that you wish to utilise." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Note: Hold the 'Ctrl' key to select multiple ranges." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine, Default:="", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If headerRng Is Nothing Then
        'notify user that the process cannot continue
'        MsgBox "You must select a range to undertake this process."
        'exit the sub
        Exit Sub
    End If


    'check how many areas were selected and that they all have 1 row and are all on the same line
    areaSelectionCount = headerRng.Areas.Count
    areaSelectionIsValid = True
    areaSelectionRow = 0
    'loop through all areas checking they are a vald header
    i = 1
    For i = 1 To areaSelectionCount
        'check selection area row count
        If headerRng.Areas(i).Rows.Count <> 1 Then
            areaSelectionIsValid = False
        End If
        'check selection area row
        If areaSelectionRow = 0 Then
            'set areaSelectionRow
            areaSelectionRow = headerRng.Areas(i).Row
        Else
            'test areaSelectionRow variable against the row of the area selection
            If areaSelectionRow <> headerRng.Areas(i).Row Then
                areaSelectionIsValid = False
            End If
        End If

    Next i


    'exit if the area selection is not valid (FALSE)
    If areaSelectionIsValid = False Then
        'notify user that the process cannot continue
        MsgBox "You may only select headings from a single row. Please try again."
        'exit the sub
        Exit Sub
    End If



    'ask the user to select the cell heading which they would like to plit their data on
    On Error Resume Next
    Set splitColRng = Application.InputBox("Select a cell from anywhere in the column which you want to use to classify (split) your data.", Default:="", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If splitColRng Is Nothing Then
        'notify user that the process cannot continue
        MsgBox "You must select a cell to undertake this process. Please start again."
        'exit the sub
        Exit Sub
    End If


    On Error GoTo errorHandling

    'turn updating off
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False




    'loop down the master data and
    lastRow = MAST.Cells(MAST.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row


    'loop down the items in the table and build an array of all themes (based on the user split cell selection)
    For i = headerRng.Row + 1 To lastRow
        'if the theme is blank then insert place holder
        If MAST.Cells(i, splitColRng.Column).Value = "" Then
            MAST.Cells(i, splitColRng.Column).Value = "Blank / TBC"
        End If
        'get the theme
        theme = MAST.Cells(i, splitColRng.Column).Value
        'check if the theme exists in the array yet
        themeExists = False
        ii = 1
        For ii = 1 To UBound(themeArray)
            If themeArray(ii) = theme Then
                'stop loop and do not add current theme to the array
                themeExists = True
            End If
        Next ii

        If themeExists = False Then
            'add current theme
            themeArray(UBound(themeArray)) = MAST.Cells(i, splitColRng.Column).Value
            ReDim Preserve themeArray(1 To UBound(themeArray) + 1)
        End If

    Next i


    'notify the user how many themes there are going to be
'    MsgBox "The table is about to be split into " & UBound(themeArray) - 1 & " seperate sheets, each containing grouped data based on the column you selected."


    'loop through the theme array and build a :
    '-sheet
    '-table
    '-rows
    'for each theme
    ii = 1
    For ii = 1 To UBound(themeArray) - 1
        'check if sheet exists
        'check if a worksheet by the name of this theme exists and create one if not
        'returns TRUE if the sheet exists in the workbook
        doesSheetExist = False
        For Each ws In Worksheets
          If Left(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(themeArray(ii), ",", ""), "/", ""), "\", ""), "[", ""), "]", ""), 25) = ws.Name Then
            doesSheetExist = True
          End If
        Next ws

        'create sheet if it does not exist
        If doesSheetExist = False Then
            'create sheet after the master sheet
            Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
            Set ws = ActiveSheet
            'max sheet name is 31 characters and cannot contain special characters
            ws.Name = Left(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(themeArray(ii), ",", ""), "/", ""), "\", ""), "[", ""), "]", ""), 25)
        Else
            'do not creat sheet but activate the existing
            Sheets(Left(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(themeArray(ii), ",", ""), "/", ""), "\", ""), "[", ""), "]", ""), 25)).Activate
            Set ws = ActiveSheet
        End If


        'delete any old data out of the sheet
        lastSheetTabRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        If lastSheetTabRow < 4 Then
            lastSheetTabRow = 4
        End If
        ws.Rows("4:" & lastSheetTabRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp


        'copy table header into each sheet tab
        headerRng.Copy
        ws.Range("B4").Select
        ws.Paste


        'insert title and time stamp details into new sheet
        ws.Range("B2").Value = themeArray(ii)
        ws.Range("B2").Font.Size = 22
        ws.Range("B2").Font.Bold = True
        ws.Range("B1").Font.Size = 8
        ws.Range("C1:D1").Font.Size = 8
        ws.Range("C1:D1").Cells.Merge
        ws.Range("B1").Value = "Timestamp : "
        ws.Range("C1").Value = Now()
        ws.Range("C1").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        ws.Range("E1").Value = "Updates must NOT be done in this worksheet!"
        ws.Range("E1").Font.Color = vbRed


        'loop down the items in the master table and copy them over to the correct sheet tabs based on selected theme/column
        sheetTabRowCounter = 1
        i = headerRng.Row + 1
        For i = headerRng.Row + 1 To lastRow
            'copy item from master into theme tab if matches the theme
            If MAST.Cells(i, splitColRng.Column).Value = themeArray(ii) Then
                'copy row
                MAST.Activate
                headerRng.Offset(i - headerRng.Row, 0).Copy
                'paste row
                ws.Activate
                ws.Cells(sheetTabRowCounter + 4, 2).Select
                ws.Paste
                'add one to the sheet row couter
                sheetTabRowCounter = sheetTabRowCounter + 1
            End If

        Next i

    Next ii






    'format new sheet
    'loop through all theme sheets and size their columns to match tre master sheet
    ii = 1
    For ii = 1 To UBound(themeArray) - 1

        Sheets(Left(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(themeArray(ii), ",", ""), "/", ""), "\", ""), "[", ""), "]", ""), 25)).Activate
        Set ws = ActiveSheet

        'loop through all of the columns on the master table and get their size
        i = headerRng.Column
        For i = headerRng.Column To (headerRng.Column + headerRng.Columns.Count + 1)
            ws.Columns(i).ColumnWidth = MAST.Columns(i).ColumnWidth
        Next i

        'loop down sheet tab and autofit all row heights
        ws.Rows.AutoFit

        ws.Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 2

        ws.Activate

        'hide gridlines
        ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False

        'freeze panes
        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
        ws.Cells(5, 1).Select
        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

        ws.Range("A1").Select

    Next ii




    'loop through all sheets and delete sheets where the timestamp exists but is older than 5 seconds
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        'check if cell contains a date
        If IsDate(ws.Range("C1").Value) = True And ws.Range("B1").Value = "Timestamp : " Then

            'delete when sheet is older than 10 seconds
            If (Now() - ws.Range("C1").Value) < 10 / 86400 Then
                'MsgBox "OK - " & Now() - ws.Range("C1").Value
            Else
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ws.Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If

        End If

    Next ws




    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'activate the master sheet
    MAST.Activate
    MAST.Range("A1").Select

    'turn updating back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'notify user process is complete
    MsgBox "Done!"

Exit Sub
errorHandling:
    'notify the user of error
    'activate the master sheet
    MAST.Activate
    MAST.Range("A1").Select

    'turn updating back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'notify user process is complete
    MsgBox "Something went wrong! Please try again." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Note: This error may be being caused by an invalid heading selection range." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "If the problem persists contact Tom Winslow for assistance."


End Sub
```

Comment: Tom, Thankyou very much for this script. This is exactly what i wanted. It was a great help. :)

Comment: No probs @Sumit. Pleased I could help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I do not suspect there is any out of the box "feature" to do this. However I would approach this as folows:

1. Sort the product by your category (so that all items going into a single workbook are line by line)
2. Do a simple VBA loop which: Checks if the product is of a new type. If yes then it should close the last open product workbook, create a new workbook e.g. using the name of the product, and saves the line to that workbook. If not then save the line to the current created and open workbook.

If you have problems with this VBA post it and we will help.